# A Basic Truth of Set Theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, foundations

Forgive me in advance if this question seems ridiculous.

Let $X$ be a set. Then "$X\neq\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}$ is false" is a true statement.

This statement says that a set is always equal to the union of its elements(points).

Is this axiomatic or can this actually be proven by by something even more obvious than the statement?

Comment: We need to use $\{x\}$, not $x$.

Comment: Do you actually mean $\bigcup_{x \in X} \{x\}$?

Comment: edited it: Just for clarification why must we use the set containing x there?

Comment: Because $\{x\}\neq x$. When you write $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ you mean the set whose elements are all the elements of all the $A_i$'s. And so $X$ might not have any elements in common with any $x\in X$; but it has elements in common with each $\{x\}$ for $x\in X$.

Comment: what if we take $X=\mathbb{R}$. Is it true then that the union over all the $x$ works out? Is there a class of sets where you don't need the singletons?

Comment: Why state it as"$A\neq B$ is false," rather than the equivalent $A=B$?

Comment: @ Thomas No special reason Tom.

Comment: Ok I think I see the reasoning: my statement about $\mathbb{R}$ is not well defined because what does one really mean by a union of elements?? Its a notion defined for sets. Intuitively though you might suspect what I want. The set $\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to all its points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "provable" you need to specify some axioms from which this to be proved.

If we consider the axioms of $\sf ZFC$, which are considered more or less the canonical set theory nowadays, then the answer is that yes. We can prove that.

First of all we need to show that if $X$ is a set then $\{\{x\}\mid x\in X\}$ is a set. This is true because $S=\{x\}\mid x\in X\}$ is a definable subset of $\mathcal P(X)$, and the latter exists from the axiom of power set. So using the separation axiom schema we conclude that $\{\{x\}\mid x\in X\}$ is a set.

Now the union $\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}$ is the union of $S$. This union exists as a consequence of the axiom of union, which states that if $A$ is a set, then $\{b\mid\exists a\in A:b\in a\}$ is also a set. Call this union of singletons $Y$.

Finally, $X=Y$ due to the axiom of extensionality. Given $x\in X$, $\{x\}$ was an element of $S$, therefore $x\in Y$, and on the other hand if $x\in Y$, then there is some $s\in S$ such that $x\in s$, but if $s\in S$ then $s=\{x'\}$ for some $x'\in X$. So if $x\in s$ it follows that $x=x'$ and therefore $x\in X$. $\square$

Comment: @ Asaf its been a while since I looked at Halmos but this reminds me of it. thx

Comment: I actually never read it!

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean "is it the case that for any set $X$, $X=\bigcup_{x \in X} \{ x \}$"? If so, then at least in ZF or an extension thereof, this is more like a definition than an axiom. Just expand definitions:

$$y \in \bigcup_{x \in X} \{ x \} \Leftrightarrow (\exists x \in X) y \in \{ x \} \Leftrightarrow (\exists x \in X) y = x \Leftrightarrow y \in X.$$

If instead you meant "is it the case that for any set $X$, $X=\bigcup_{x \in X} x$", then this is false. For example, when $X = \{ \emptyset \}$, the resulting union is $\emptyset$, which is a different set ($X$ has an element, $\emptyset$ does not).

In a set theory other than ZF or an extension thereof, everything should go through as long as all of the objects are even defined, but they needn't be defined. For example, in NF, when $X$ is a set, $\{ \{ x \} : x \in X \}$ need not be a set, and so we need not be able to take its union.

Comment: That can't be "a definition", it has to be a theorem (or an axiom). Because $\bigcup$ has a definition of its own, and $X$ itself has no definition anyway (and you can't define it using itself, so saying that $X$ is **defined** as $\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}$ is circular).

Comment: It is a definition in the sense that $y \in \bigcup_{x \in X} f(x)$ is defined to mean $(\exists x \in X) y \in f(x)$, provided $\{ f(x) : x \in X \}$ exists and unions exist (both of which are true in ZF and extensions thereof, provided $f$ is definable). I agree that this is somewhat abuse of terminology, which is why I wrote out the expansion. I also agree that it is, strictly speaking, a theorem. But it is a theorem whose proof is a trivial expansion of definitions.

Comment: The definition of the union is one, the fact that the union over $\{\{x\}\mid x\in X\}$ is a different thing. It might be almost trivial, but it is still a theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The claim that the statement "$X\neq \bigcup_{x\in X}{x}$ is false" is not true.  What I believe you mean is $X\neq \bigcup_{x\in X}{\{x\}}$.

For example, take $X=\{\{0\},\{1\}\}$.  Then $\bigcup{X}=\{0,1\}\neq X$.

However, the claim that "$X\neq \bigcup_{x\in X}{x}$ is false" is true.  To see this, notice that $\{y\}\subset \bigcup_{x\in X}{\{x\}}$ for every $y\in X$, so that $y\in \bigcup_{x\in X}{\{x\}}$ for every $y\in X$.  This shows us that $X\subset \bigcup_{x\in X}{x}$.  To show the converse, notice that if $y\in \bigcup_{x\in X}{\{x\}}$, then by definition there is $\{z\}$ such that $y\in \{z\}$ with $z\in X$.  But then $y=z$, and thus $y\in X$.  This shows us that $\bigcup_{x\in X}{x}\subset X$.

Putting these two together gives us $\bigcup_{x\in X}{\{x\}}=X$ is true (which is equivalent to the statement you gave).

The reason the original statement was false was due to the fact that writing $\bigcup_{x\in X}{x}$ means the collection of all *elements in $x$ for $x\in X$*.

Comment: ah, I see the issue. With this adjustment, is the statement taken on faith or provable by other means?

Comment: I expanded the answer that proves the claim (though in many senses it depends only upon the definition of what the notation $\bigcup_{x\in X}{x}$ means).  It's certainly provable, however; claims in math should never be taken on faith in general (unless it's been proven by someone somewhere) (It could be debated that axioms are 'taken on faith', but whether this is accurate or not might depend upon the mathematician.  ).

Answer (score 0):

You can prove the desideratum by the axiom "$\neg \neg \phi \Rightarrow \phi$" and using a usefull trick: To prove that $A=B$, prove that $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$.

The first, suppose $y\in X$, then $\{y\}\subseteq \bigcup_{y\in X} \{y\}$ as $\{y\}$ is one of the sets being united, so $y\in \{y\} \subseteq \bigcup_{y\in X} \{y\}$.

The second, suppose  $y\in \bigcup_{y\in X} \{y\}$then there is some $y'$ st $y\in \{y'\}$ and $y'\in X$, so $y=y'$ and then $y\in X$ as desired.